# Don't understand this python For loop

Tags: python

I'm working through a [tutorial](http://pyneurgen.sourceforge.net/tutorial_nn.html) which includes this code:

```
for position, target in population_gen(population):
    pos = float(position)
    all_inputs.append([random.random(), pos * factor])
    all_targets.append([target])
```

I don't fully understand how the `for` loop works. In particular: what is the loop iterating through exactly? I'm only familiar with simple examples like `for i in mylist:`. How can there be a function call on the right-hand side of `in`, and two things separated by a comma on the left-hand side?

Comment: I had this same question. You aren't alone.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The function population_gen is returning a list of tuples, which are unpacked automatically into variable names using this syntax.

So basically, you're getting something like the following as return value from the function:

```
[("pos1", "target1"), ("pos2", "target2"), ]
```

Given this example, in the the for loop's first iteration, the variables "position" and "target" will have the values:

```
position = "pos1"
target = "target1"
```

In second iteration:

```
position = "pos2"
target = "target2"
```

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer! Does it also work if `population_gen` is a dictionary?

Answer (score 7):

Tuple unpacking.

```
for a, b in [(1, 2), (3, 4)]:
  print a
  print b
  print 'next!'
```

And the function is just a function.

Answer (score 3):

The function either returns a sequence or serves as something called a "generator:" it spits out successive elements in a sequence for the caller to iterate through. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained) concerning the yield keyword has some thorough discussion of how these work.

As for the comma, since the function (apparently) returns a two-tuple, the comma-separated list of names is a convenient way to name individual elements of the tuple without having to unpack them yourself.

Answer (score 3):

It's called [tuple unpacking](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html). The `population_gen` (generator) function yields tuples containing exactly two elements. In python, you can assign several variables to tuples like this

```
a, b = (1, 2)
```

So in this `for` loop, you directly put the two tuple values from the current iteration item into your two variables `position` and `target`.