# Understanding for loops in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to create a `for` loop and I ran into problems. I don't understand how these loops work, and I think the problem is because I'm using the `for` syntax incorrectly.

From what I understand, a `for` loop should look like

```
for w in words:
    print(w, len(w))
```

But *how exactly does it work*?

To try to be specific: What does the `w` mean? How can I know what to write between `for` and `in`, and after `in`? What exactly happens when the code runs?

---

<sub>For a more technical breakdown of how `for` loops are implemented, see [How does a Python for loop with iterable work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292189).</sub>

Comment: Other languages call it a 'foreach' loop, if that helps.

Comment: I'm surprised that I haven't seen more demand for a canonical like this. The equivalent of this question is asked **constantly** on the r/learnpython subreddit.

Comment: Hmm. Looking further into the original question... while OP *was asking*, superficially, about the syntax, it seems that the underlying problem is that OP wanted to iterate over a list of numbers, but didn't **have** a list of numbers to iterate over. If asked today and I saw it in the original form, I would have instead closed it as a duplicate of [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `for` loop takes each item in an [*iterable*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/) and assigns that value to a variable like `w` or `number`, each time through the loop. The code inside the loop is repeated with each of those values being re-assigned to that variable, until the loop runs out of items.

Note that the name used **doesn't affect** what values are assigned each time through the loop. Code like `for letter in myvar:` doesn't force the program to choose letters. The name `letter` just gets the next item from `myvar` each time through the loop. What the "next item" is, depends entirely on what `myvar` is.

As a metaphor, imagine that you have a shopping cart full of items, and the cashier is looping through them one at a time:

```
for eachitem in mybasket: 
    # add item to total
    # go to next item.
```

If `mybasket` were actually a bag of apples, then `eachitem` that is `in mybasket` would be an individual apple; but if `mybasket` is actually a shopping cart, then the entire bag could itself meaningfully be a single "item".

Comment: It's important to understand that the loop **assigns to** whatever is put between `for` and `in`, just like if you used `=`. It's possible (although very much not recommended) to, for example, use an element in an existing list to store the iteration variable, like `for x[0] in y:`, which will replace the `[0]` element of `x` with a new element from `y` each time.

Comment: Less obscurely, we can use unpacking syntax between `for` and `in`, if we iterate over a sequence of iterables: `for x, y in [[1,2], [3,4]]` will mean that the first time through the loop, `x` is equal to `1` and `y` is equal to `2`; the second time through, `x` is equal to `3` and `y` is equal to `4`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463683

Comment: It's also important to understand that whatever is assigned here, *doesn't need to have existed before*. Some beginners are confused by `for eachitem in mybasket:` if/because there was no previous `eachitem` in the program. But, again - this is an **assignment**, and there is **nothing special** about the first time a value is assigned. Python does not have anything like variable initialization or declaration; if you want to assign something, you just do it.

Answer (score 3):

A `for` loop works on an [*iterable*](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable): i.e., an object that represents an ordered collection of other objects (it doesn't have to actually store them; but most kinds of iterable, called *sequences*, do). A string is an iterable:

```
>>> for c in "this is iterable":
...     print(c, end=" ")
...
t  h  i  s     i  s     i  t  e  r  a  b  l  e
```

However, a number is not:

```
>>> for x in 3:
...     print("this is not")
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The built-in [`range` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) allows an easy way to iterate over a range of numbers:

```
>>> for x in range(3):
...     print(x)
...
0
1
2
```

In 2.x, `range` simply creates a list with those integer values; in 3.x, it [makes a special kind of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/) that calculates the numbers on demand [when the `for` loop asks for them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151).

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, Python loops over an *iterable* object, such as a string, list or tuple. For a list, it will loop through the list elements:

```
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> for n in numbers: print(n)
1
2
3
4
5
```

For a string, it will loop through individual characters (technically, Unicode code points):

```
>>> my_happy_string = "cheese"
>>> for c in my_happy_string: print(c)
c
h
e
e
s
e
```

Here is another example with a list of words:

```
>>> list_of_words = ["hello", "cat", "world", "mouse"]
>>> for word in list_of_words: print(word)
hello
cat
world
mouse
```

If you want a `for` loop that would start at `0` and end at `10`, you can use the built-in `range` function:

```
>>> for i in range(0, 10): print(i)
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score -1):

What you have is more like a `foreach` loop.

Maybe something like this:

```
input = raw_input("> ") #separate with spaces
sum = 0
numbers = [int(n) for n in input.split()]
for number in numbers:
    sum = sum + number
print sum
```

Comment: Or: `sum(int(n) for n in raw_input("> ").split())`.

Comment: @iCodez But how will I know if your compact Python is correct without the `print` statement? :)

Comment: LOL.  I made that in the Python interpreter where you don't need `print`. :)

Comment: I'm not sure how this explanation is helpful. Python doesn't have a `foreach` loop. Python's `for` loop is _always_ the equivalent of a "foreach" in other languages, and it's certainly not more of a "foreach" in the OP's code than in yours. And I doubt a novice who doesn't understand `for` loops is going to be helped by knowing that some other languages call the same thing `foreach`.