# I was reading my textbook, and I am confused what the importance of vowels_in_word = "" does?

Tags: python

I was reading my textbook, and I am confused what the importance of vowels_in_word = "" does? I'm not sure what the significance of it is. Does it just hold the the values of char? Also, when creating `for` loops, what is char? Can you just assign your own variable even if its not assigned anywhere in the program?

```
def get_vowels_in_word(word):
    vowel_str = "aeiouy"
    vowels_in_word = ""
    for char in word:
        if char in vowel_str:
            vowels_in_word += char
    return vowels_in_word
```

Comment: It means vowels_in_word variable is initialized to be empty. The code is finding the vowels in the word

Comment: The for loop iterates over the word one character (char) at a time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't Understand For Loops Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257862/cant-understand-for-loops-python)

Comment: "Can you just assign your own variable even if its not assigned anywhere in the program?" I can't understand the question. Of course you can assign to variables. If something is assigned multiple times, then one of those assignments is first; and the first time it happens, it didn't happen before (that's what "first" means). Notice how you **don't** have the same question about `vowel_str = "aeiouy"`? **Why not**?

Answer (score 1):

It initializes the string `vowels_in_word` to be empty. The following for loop then appends characters to it with the `+=` operator.

The `+=` operation would throw an exception if `vowels_in_word` had not previously been initialized to be a string of 0 characters.

Comment: Could i name char something else, or is that built into python? Sorry if this is a bad question, Im trying to teach python to myself

Comment: @user7433120 You can name it whatever you want. You should really be reading a tutorial, this isn't an appropriate question for stack-overflow, especially if you aren't showing any research effort. Don't use this site as a tutoring service.