# Why don't we have to declare the variable in this python for loop?

Tags: python, variables

So I'm learning Python and I'm slowly picking up the pieces. I'm taking a practice quiz and I sadly had to go to stackoverflow to solve it. I tried to disassemble the code and saw it has x variables in the for loop, which are never declared/referenced in the code.

Is there an explanation / rule of thumb for when I need to initialize these variables? I notice I sometimes don't get errors when I don't declare and sometimes I do. Maybe I'm misunderstanding (I'm really misunderstanding).

```
def squares(start, end):
    return [ x*x for x in range(start,end+1) ] # Create the required list comprehension.


print(squares(2, 3)) # Should print [4, 9]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Gd8R.png)

Comment: `.. for x in ..` is a declaration of x.  Granted, there's a reference to `x*x` that happens _before_ the declaration, but that's just the syntax of list comprehensions.  You'll get used to it.

Comment: Maybe see this answer too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257862/understanding-for-loops-in-python/19257985#19257985

Comment: @beroe That only talks about normal for loops, which I think the OP understands. Their confusion is about generator expressions, which are kind of backwards.

Comment: True @Barmar. I figured the other answers/comments explained the correspondence between list comprehension and `for` loops, so added that in case the confusion was more fundamental.

Comment: @beroe I searched that question for the words "comprehension" and "generator" and didn't find any, so I didn't think it mentioned them.

Answer (score 1):

The `x` in the loop statement is the declaration of the variable. Essentially, think of it the same as a for loop

```py
# x is declared here and used within the block
for x in range(0, 10):
    print(x)
```

In a list comprehension (what you're looking at), it's the same except it's shifted a little to the right.

```py
[ x*x for x in range(0,10) ]
          ^ declaration
```